# Interface property undefined when trying to set value?

Tags: angular, typescript, class, interface

Here is my basketball Player class and ITeam & IStats interfaces:

```
export class Player {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  position: string;
  team: ITeam;
  stat: IStats;

  get fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}

export interface ITeam {
  id: string;
  abbreviation: string;
  name: string;
  city: string;
}

export interface IStats {
  GP: number;
  Min: number;
  FGM: number;
  FGA: number;
  TPM: number;
  TPA: number;
  FTM: number;
  FTA: number;
  OR: number;
  TR: number;
  AS: number;
  ST: number;
  TO: number;
  BK: number;
  PF: number;
  DQ: number;
  PTS: number;
  TC: number;
  EJ: number;
  FF: number;
  Sta: number;
}
```

When I loop through my data in my component, it errors when I try to set the player.team.abbreviation property with ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'abbreviation' of undefined

```
  createPlayer(playerArray) {
    let player: IPlayer = new Player();

    player.id = playerArray[0];
    player.firstName = playerArray[1];
    player.lastName = playerArray[2];
    player.team.abbreviation = playerArray[3];
...
    }
```

Why is player.team undefined?

Comment: Add a constructor to the Player class that instantiates the team and stats properties to an object that is the shape the property expects. Without instantiating those properties, they are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you R.Richards, this update now works:

```
export class Player {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  position: string;
  team: ITeam;
  stat: IStats;

  constructor() {
    this.team = {} as ITeam;
    this.stat = {} as IStats;
  }

  get fullName(): string {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```